# Trying to figure out why when writing to file, the last character written is being duplicated when cout looks fine on display

Tags: fstream

Question = Trying to figure out why the write to file for

```
 myfile.open ("Crypt103Data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
 myfile <<tab2[code1];
 myfile.close();
```

is writing the last character twice to Crypt103Data.txt when the cout which also runs for the same iterations within the while loop displays proper without the extra character write appended to file?

If you enter something like Hello_World you might see something like r$cc7fq7UcX depending on what seed value to entered which gives the output a unique output that is dependent on the seed key. While r$cc7fq7UcX is observed correctly on the screen below the Hello_World , what is written to file is r$cc7fq7UcXX where the last character is written twice and it should only be r$cc7fq7UcX . Not sure why this happens when the cout print to display and file write appended happens for the same iterations within the while loop. Instead of placing a band aid in to trim the last character from the file after each line is written, there must be a fix for this odd bug that someone here might be able to point out. Maybe I am using sloppy programming that is causing for this to occur. I am using the Bloodshed Dev c++ 4.9.9.2 IDE btw

When decrypted, due to this extra character write of the last character the output duplicated, it is decrypted as Hello_Worldd which is the problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
// 12/30/2015 - Added string random shuffle
// 12/31/2015 - Added custom seed for random shuffle so seed acts a crypt key
// 1/4/2016 - Added ability to enter string and have while loop process v1.00
// 1/5/2016 - Added characters , and ; to supported characters which were missing from v1.01
// 1/8/2015 - Source code trash cleanup & offset band aid removed for IF statement logic +1 array offset v1.02
// 1/8/2015 - Added write to file for coded data storage eliminating need to copy/paste output to a text file v1.03
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int seed1=0;
    int code1=0;
    int run=1;
    int again=1;
    int test=1;
    char ch1;
    char ch2;


        while(again==1){



    cout<<" Crypt Version 1.03\n\n";
    cout<<"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n";
    cout<<" Enter Integer Seed: \n"; // Asks user to input integer seed
    cout<<"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n";
    cin >> seed1; // Input user seed
    cout<<"\n\n"<<"Crypt String Key =\n\n";

              ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("Crypt103Key.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
  myfile <<seed1<<"\n";
  myfile.close();






    //Initialize Valid Characters for String Shuffle Output
    //Note Bug corrected with blank space for \ by use of escape character proceeding
    string str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_-+=?<>:\\/~.,;";



    srand(seed1); // Allows user custom seeded starting algorithm position for random

    random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end()); // Shuffle the string
    cout << str << "\n\n\n"; // Output the shuffle sequence


        //Pass String Output into an array to pair up pointer value with associated character

    string tmp = str; //Pass str output to string tmp
    char tab2[128]; // Memory Allocation for array population
    strncpy(tab2, tmp.c_str(), sizeof(tab2)); //string copy tmp into tab2 array
    tab2[sizeof(tab2) - 1] = 0;


        cout<<"Enter Info to Crypt in correct case\n";
        cout<<"To Exit Inner Program enter  ( ` ) \n\n\n";

    while(run==1){

    cin>>ch1;

    if (ch1=='A'){
                code1=0;
                }
    else if (ch1=='B'){
         code1=1;
         }
    else if (ch1=='C'){
         code1=2;
         }
    else if (ch1=='D'){
         code1=3;
         }
    else if (ch1=='E'){
         code1=4;
         }
    else if (ch1=='F'){
         code1=5;
         }
    else if (ch1=='G'){
         code1=6;
         }
    else if (ch1=='H'){
         code1=7;
         }
    else if (ch1=='I'){
         code1=8;
         }
    else if (ch1=='J'){
         code1=9;
         }
    else if (ch1=='K'){
         code1=10;
         }
    else if (ch1=='L'){
         code1=11;
         }
    else if (ch1=='M'){
         code1=12;
         }
    else if (ch1=='N'){
         code1=13;
         }
    else if (ch1=='O'){
         code1=14;
         }
    else if (ch1=='P'){
         code1=15;
         }
    else if (ch1=='Q'){
         code1=16;
         }
    else if (ch1=='R'){
         code1=17;
         }
    else if (ch1=='S'){
         code1=18;
         }
    else if (ch1=='T'){
         code1=19;
         }
    else if (ch1=='U'){
         code1=20;
         }
    else if (ch1=='V'){
         code1=21;
         }
    else if (ch1=='W'){
         code1=22;
         }
    else if (ch1=='X'){
         code1=23;
         }
    else if (ch1=='Y'){
         code1=24;
         }
    else if (ch1=='Z'){
         code1=25;
         }
    else if (ch1=='a'){
         code1=26;
         }
    else if (ch1=='b'){
         code1=27;
         }
    else if (ch1=='c'){
         code1=28;
         }
    else if (ch1=='d'){
         code1=29;
         }
    else if (ch1=='e'){
         code1=30;
         }
    else if (ch1=='f'){
         code1=31;
         }
    else if (ch1=='g'){
         code1=32;
         }
    else if (ch1=='h'){
         code1=33;
         }
    else if (ch1=='i'){
         code1=34;
         }
    else if (ch1=='j'){
         code1=35;
         }
    else if (ch1=='k'){
         code1=36;
         }
    else if (ch1=='l'){
         code1=37;
         }
    else if (ch1=='m'){
         code1=38;
         }
    else if (ch1=='n'){
         code1=39;
         }
    else if (ch1=='o'){
         code1=40;
         }
    else if (ch1=='p'){
         code1=41;
         }
    else if (ch1=='q'){
         code1=42;
         }
    else if (ch1=='r'){
         code1=43;
         }
    else if (ch1=='s'){
         code1=44;
         }
    else if (ch1=='t'){
         code1=45;
         }
    else if (ch1=='u'){
         code1=46;
         }
    else if (ch1=='v'){
         code1=47;
         }
    else if (ch1=='w'){
         code1=48;
         }
    else if (ch1=='x'){
         code1=49;
         }
    else if (ch1=='y'){
         code1=50;
         }
    else if (ch1=='z'){
         code1=51;
         }
    else if (ch1=='1'){
         code1=52;
         }
    else if (ch1=='2'){
         code1=53;
         }
    else if (ch1=='3'){
         code1=54;
         }
    else if (ch1=='4'){
         code1=55;
         }
    else if (ch1=='5'){
         code1=56;
         }
    else if (ch1=='6'){
         code1=57;
         }
    else if (ch1=='7'){
         code1=58;
         }
    else if (ch1=='8'){
         code1=59;
         }
    else if (ch1=='9'){
         code1=60;
         }
    else if (ch1=='0'){
         code1=61;
         }
    else if (ch1=='!'){
         code1=62;
         }
    else if (ch1=='@'){
         code1=63;
         }
    else if (ch1=='#'){
         code1=64;
         }
    else if (ch1=='$'){
         code1=65;
         }
    else if (ch1=='%'){
         code1=66;
         }
    else if (ch1=='^'){
         code1=67;
         }
    else if (ch1=='&'){
         code1=68;
         }
    else if (ch1=='*'){
         code1=69;
         }
    else if (ch1=='('){
         code1=70;
         }
    else if (ch1==')'){
         code1=71;
         }
    else if (ch1=='_'){
         code1=72;
         }
    else if (ch1=='-'){
         code1=73;
         }
    else if (ch1=='+'){
         code1=74;
         }
    else if (ch1=='='){
         code1=75;
         }
    else if (ch1=='?'){
         code1=76;
         }
    else if (ch1=='<'){
         code1=77;
         }
    else if (ch1=='>'){
         code1=78;
         }
    else if (ch1==':'){
         code1=79;
         }
    else if (ch1=='\\'){ // Escape Character \ needed to allow \ check
         code1=80;
         }
    else if (ch1=='/'){
         code1=81;
         }
    else if (ch1=='~'){
         code1=82;
         }
    else if (ch1=='.'){
         code1=83;
         }
    else if (ch1==','){
         code1=84;
         }
    else if (ch1==';'){
         code1=85;
         }
    else if (ch1=='\`'){ //Escape Character \ before ` to exit
         run=0; //Run = False at 0 and leaves while loop
         }
    else {
         cout<<"Invalid Input = No Match\n\n";
         }
         cout<<tab2[code1];




    myfile.open ("Crypt103Data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
  myfile <<tab2[code1];
  myfile.close();

         }// end inner while loop
         //Add line return in file to seperate the data per line
             myfile.open ("Crypt103Data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
  myfile <<"    "<<"\n";
  myfile.close();
  test=1;
  while(test==1){
          system("CLS");
          cout<<"Enter Y to continue or N to end \n\n\n";
          cin>>ch2;
          if (ch2=='N'||ch2=='n'){
                again=0;
                test=0;
                }
    else if (ch2=='Y'||ch2=='y'){
         again=1;
         test=0;
         run=1;
         system("CLS");
         }
    else {
         cout<<"Invalid Input, please choose Y or N \n\n";
         test=1;
         }   
         } 


} // end outter while loop

    system("CLS");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You are obviously learning, but that if statement is enough to drive anyone mad. You can do arithmetic with char variables, so for example: `code1 = ch1 - 'A'` will save you a massive amount of time.

Comment: So I would have all 86 lines of code1=ch1-'ascii character' and then a single IF statement to break out of the loop if  ( ` ) is entered?  So this instruction is a test that if  ch1 is equal to 'ascii character' it passes the ascii value to code1 like casting a char to an int where the ascii value can be grabbed?

Comment: No - look for the pattern! 'A' -> 0, 'B' -> 1, 'C' -> 2, etc. Variable ch1 is a char that contains the ASCII value of the character: 65 for A, 66 for B, 67 for C, etc. So, for A-Z, all you need to do is subtract 65 (or 'A') from ch1 to get your code1. For a-z you will need to subtract 'a' and add 26. The rest you can figure out.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that... btw does this lengthy IF logic have something there that is causing for the extra duplicate character write in the while loop that correcting to clean up the logic with your suggestion will cure?

Comment: I don't know. The trouble is, with that much code, you can't see the wood for the trees. Trim it down. Better still, put the mapping logic in a separate function out of the way. Then you will be able to see what is going on. Also, it is bad practice to open and close the file for each character. Very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this... makes sense. I started on GW-Basic and Basic for TRS80 years ago and got into C++ many years later however I am a hobbyist programmer and so you can probably see in my code remnants of Basic's structure in my C++. I need to learn to make separate functions vs everything mashed together as one. Many thanks!

Comment: Fixed issue with the additional appended character write by setting a write delay in my loop. Allowing it to loop once and then enable writing to file at the start of the second loop. Its still rather strange that exiting the loop wrote last char 2x prior

Comment: while(run==1){
       cin>>ch1;
       //supress write to file until 1 loop run ( bug fix for double character write )
       if(writeenable==1){
       myfile.open ("Crypt104Data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
       myfile <<tab2[code1];
       myfile.close();
       }
       else{
      //do nothing and continue
      }
      writeenable=1; //enable write to file

Comment: Now that I have this issue resolved I can clean up that IF logic mess with your suggestion rghome. Thanks for the help